Bean injection into Hibernate BeforeExecutionGenerator
I'm using Hibernate's BeforeExecutionGenerator together with IdGeneratorType annotation to generate custom ids for my entities.
How could I inject some beans (or config properties) into my implementation of generator?
Here is the code:
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity")
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @MyIdGeneratorValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    //other fields
}

@IdGeneratorType(MyIdGenerator.class)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD})
public @interface MyIdGeneratorValue {
}


public class MyIdGenerator implements BeforeExecutionGenerator {

    //doesn't work
    @Inject
    OtherService service;

    @Override
    public Object generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object owner, Object currentValue,
                           EventType eventType) {
        return service.nextId();
    }

    @Override
    public EnumSet<EventType> getEventTypes() {
        return INSERT_ONLY;
    }

}


I've already tried simply adding @Inject on service field, also tried making generator class @ApplicationScoped, but no result.
I'm using Quarkus as CDI implementation.

You need to retrieve OtherService in a programmatic way using CDI.current().select(OtherService.class).get()

Thanks for your reply! Is it somehow guarantied that OtherService would already be constructed by the moment of injection?

Yes, if you retrieve service in generate method all should works flawless

Works great! By the way I also had to add @io.quarkus.arc.Unremovable on OtherService.

Yes, you're right; beans retrieved using programmatic lookup are not discovered by quarkus and are marked as removable.
